# About event to Latitude and Longitude in C#

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, boundless-suite

I am beginning to study Ready GXP and I would like to know which event receives Latitude and Longitude and passes them to the browser for execution in C#.

Comment: I have edited the text for good English, Felipe, but I'm not entirely sure whether it now reflects your original question.  Please modify it further if you need to make any corrections.

Comment: My application depends of a file (app.js) generated by the command - ant init - Ubuntu. In this application is found many functions with methods. So my question is what would be the method used to capture the coordinates (longitute and latitude) for the C# get it.

Comment: Follows the OpenGIS Official site. Guide of my studies. workshops.opengeo.org/gxp/introduction/index.html